# Restoring radio selection upon revisiting a page

Tags: php, html, session

I have a simple task: get information from a radio post, save it into a session, then, when i revisit the page with the radios at some later point, i can still see which radio I had selected. This is the code I have:

```
if(isset($_POST["question1"])){
    echo $_SESSION["question1"]=$_POST["question1"]."<br />";}
else{echo $_SESSION["question1"]="";};

//Checking
<?php print_r($_SESSION["question1"]);?>
<input type="radio" name="question31" value="A" <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION["question31"])){
      if ($_SESSION["question31"]=="A"{echo "checked";};};>/?>A
<input type="radio" name="question31" value="B" <?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION["question31"])){
      if ($_SESSION["question31"] =="B"){echo "checked";};};?>/>B
```

The page submits inputs to itself, just incase anyone is wondering about a page two (for this reason, you will find i used the isset function as a condition, prohibits error notices, AND, the page only saves the Inputs into sessions once something has been posted).

Once the page sends Inputs to itself, it saves them into sessions. If the session data is equivalent to the value of a radio, then it should check it. This way, even if I visit other pages and come back to this one, the selected radio still should be selected. I'm afraid this doesn't happen.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What does this do on line #2? `echo $_SESSION["question31"]=$_POST["question31"]."<br />";`

Comment: How is line #4 not crashing your script? `echo $_SESSION[""]="";};`

Comment: You should turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very beginning of your script.

Comment: okay, line 4 is killing me too.....editing now

Comment: use a cookie simple as that

Comment: @Mr.coder: I would use Cookies, but some users disable Cookies on their Browsers right? I'm trying to create something that isn't restricted.

Comment: `localStorage` then... but Javascript can be disable too, indeed

Comment: ok so if they block a cookie why dont you create a text file on their computer and then store the data in it,now they wont stop your app from creating a textfile right???

Comment: The user might disable cookies. They can probably disable whatever else they need to disable in their computer as well. They might stop using your application too.. Lol. it's their choice, you can't do anything about it. Otherwise have a db or something, store the info in **your** server.

Comment: @user3651945 calling `session_start();` creates a **[cookie](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)** though...